# How to SSH into my Android Phone's command prompt

Tags: ssh, termux

I have a **non-rooted** Android phone with the [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en_US) app installed. I can run `ifconfig` on the phone's terminal and see the IP address of wlan0, and I can ping the phone's IP from the terminal on my computer. Is it possible to SSH into it from a computer on the same network? If so, what would the username and password be?

I know the `openssh` package is installed on the phone:
`apt list | grep openssh` returns
`openssh/stable,now 8.1p1-4 arm [installed]`.

I can also run the `ssh` command in the phone's terminal (Termux).

Are there any extra packages I would have to install via `pkg` or `apt`? Please let me know, anything helps.

Comment: To connect to a device via SSH, there has to be an SSH server/SSH daemon running. Is `sshd` running on your device? This is typically not the case, as it's not needed.

Comment: @GiantTree Makes sense; how would I know whether or not `sshd` is running? And if it is, do you know what the `ssh` credentials would be?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes thank you soooo much! ;) That was exactly what I wanted!